# Android rtsp url not loading

Tags: android, streaming

I'm trying to play an rtsp stream using MediaPlayer in android and the application seems to always become stuck on MediaPlayer.prepare();

The url is valid as I tested it using VLC on my desktop.

Any ideas why the application is not preparing the stream.

```
class InitializeService extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            player.prepare();
            Log.d("Play", "Player prepared");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fallback();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fallback();
        }

    }
}
```

The log statement is never reached.

Update 1:
Sorry I forgot to mention that the stream will always be in 3gp format. Here is a url rtsp://r2---sn-p5qlsu76.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnTXOVs7Kwo8xMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp

Answer (score 0):

Your stream might not be of a format supported by Android.

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html to see if Android supports it.

Comment: It's a 3gpp stream. here is an example url rtsp://r2---sn-p5qlsu76.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnTXOVs7Kwo8xMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was android l that wasn't able to play the streams.